# Creating multi-field group rankings

Tags: r, grouping, ranking

For the following simplified data frame, I've calculated a rank for each School within each State, within each Test. The problem is that my rank is continuous, and I want to reset it with each change in School-State-Test Group.

```
School<-rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=10)
State<-rep(c("NY","NJ"),times=20)
Test<-rep(c("LSAT", "MCAT", "GRE","TOEFL","ACT"), times=8)
Grade<-trunc(rep((seq(from=500, to=600,length.out=4))))
dat<-data.frame(Test,State,School,Grade)
```

When I add this ranking logic,

```
dat$rank <- NA
dat$rank[order(dat$Test,dat$State,dat$Grade)] <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat[order(dat$rank),]
View(dat[order(dat$rank),])
```

the first 20 rows of my output look like this:

```
    Test State School Grade rank
10   ACT    NJ      A   533    1
30   ACT    NJ      C   533    2
20   ACT    NJ      B   600    3
40   ACT    NJ      D   600    4
5    ACT    NY      A   500    5
25   ACT    NY      C   500    6
15   ACT    NY      B   566    7
35   ACT    NY      D   566    8
18   GRE    NJ      B   533    9
38   GRE    NJ      D   533   10
8    GRE    NJ      A   600   11
28   GRE    NJ      C   600   12
13   GRE    NY      B   500   13
33   GRE    NY      D   500   14
3    GRE    NY      A   566   15
23   GRE    NY      C   566   16
6   LSAT    NJ      A   533   17
26  LSAT    NJ      C   533   18
16  LSAT    NJ      B   600   19
36  LSAT    NJ      D   600   20
```

I want them to look like this. Please note that the tie-breaker is the school. If School A and School C both have grades of 533 in NJ on the ACT, School A will come first based on alpha-order. It's OK that lower scores have lower ranks.

```
    Test State School Grade rank
10   ACT    NJ      A   533    1
30   ACT    NJ      C   533    2
20   ACT    NJ      B   600    3
40   ACT    NJ      D   600    4
5    ACT    NY      A   500    1
25   ACT    NY      C   500    2
15   ACT    NY      B   566    3
35   ACT    NY      D   566    4
18   GRE    NJ      B   533    1
38   GRE    NJ      D   533    2
8    GRE    NJ      A   600    3
28   GRE    NJ      C   600    4
13   GRE    NY      B   500    1
33   GRE    NY      D   500    2
3    GRE    NY      A   566    3
23   GRE    NY      C   566    4
6   LSAT    NJ      A   533    1
26  LSAT    NJ      C   533    2
16  LSAT    NJ      B   600    3
36  LSAT    NJ      D   600    4
```

I'd appreciate an guidance about how to approach this ranking within groups problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 dat%>%
 group_by(Test,State)%>%
 mutate(Rank=row_number())%>%
 arrange(Test,State, Rank) %>%
 head()
#       Test State School Grade Rank
#    1  ACT    NJ      A   533    1
#    2  ACT    NJ      C   533    2
#    3  ACT    NJ      B   600    3
#    4  ACT    NJ      D   600    4
#    5  ACT    NY      A   500    1
#    6  ACT    NY      C   500    2
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you comment on the difference between your dplyr approach and the plyr approach from @jalapic? For someone new to R, is plyr a better/easier entry-level package?

Comment: @user3614783.  `dplyr` is advanced version of `plyr`.  It can be used for large datasets as it is faster.  Personally, I like the syntax of `dplyr` more easier to understand. Regarding the difference, jalapic used the `rank` method, I used a function `row_number()` unique to `dplyr`.  For a new user, I would think that the syntax will be easier with `dplyr`.  I may be wrong too :-)

Comment: I read http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf, but still don't understand how %>% functions in the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a good time to use ddply from plyr

```
library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(Test, State), transform,
      myrank = rank(Grade, ties.method="first"))
```

This returns the correct rank order.  You can sort the dataframe as you wish then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave` in order to rank within groups. For example, you might do

```
rankFirst <- function(x) rank(x, ties="first")
dat$Rank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State, FUN=rankFirst))
```

If you you want to break ties by the alphabetical school name, you would want to sort the data frame by school first to ensure that result

```
dat <- dat[order(dat$School), ]
dat$Rank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State, FUN=rankFirst))
```

The `ave` and `rank` with `ties="first"` should take care of everything else

Comment: Did you try a "naked" `rank` with `ave` first?

Comment: @BondedDust Yes. Didn't like the default "ties" method.

Comment: @BondedDust I don't get the error if I name the column "Rank". I do get the error if name the new column "rank" and I run it twice. That is because you are creating column named "rank" in `dat` so when you run it the second time, `rank` is resolving to the column in `dat` because with the `with` and you don't have the `()` from the function call to let R know you want a function (which is my `rank(x)` still works). Therefore, by specifying `base::rank`, you eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Yet another gotcha' for the `with` function.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as MrFlick, but I would point out that there is an R functiuon named rank which will handle ties by averaging the results of `order`:

```
> dat$rank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State,  FUN=order) )
> dat$avgrank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State,  FUN=function(x) rank(x)) )
> dat[ order(dat$Test, dat$State, dat$rank) , ]
    Test State School Grade rank avgrank
10   ACT    NJ      A   533    1     1.5
30   ACT    NJ      C   533    2     1.5
20   ACT    NJ      B   600    3     3.5
40   ACT    NJ      D   600    4     3.5
5    ACT    NY      A   500    1     1.5
25   ACT    NY      C   500    2     1.5
15   ACT    NY      B   566    3     3.5
35   ACT    NY      D   566    4     3.5
28   GRE    NJ      C   600    1     3.5
8    GRE    NJ      A   600    2     3.5
38   GRE    NJ      D   533    3     1.5
18   GRE    NJ      B   533    4     1.5
23   GRE    NY      C   566    1     3.5
3    GRE    NY      A   566    2     3.5
```

If anyone knows why this fails I'm all ears:

```
> dat$avgrank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State,  FUN=rank) )
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: Did you accidentally create an object called "rank" in your global environment? Or was there an existing "rank" in `dat`? I do not get the same failure as you. (It runs fine.) Maybe `dat$avgrank <- with(dat, ave(Grade, Test, State,  FUN=base::rank) )` will eliminate ambiguity

Comment: `rank` is the base function in my global environment, (and I have no data object named "rank" although that shouldn't matter) but using `base::rank` does succeed. Interestingly putting it in as `'rank'` also succeeds